# Couldn't connect to development server - REACT NATIVE - ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Im trying to debug my app in my phone, but everytime I run it in android studio the phone says:

```
Couldn't connect to development server
```

[image]

already run `npm start` in my project

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

run this in your console
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081